# Memory Limit exceedeed. For the Dijkstra algorithm based on the binary heap

Tags: c, algorithm, dijkstra

trying to implement a Dijkstra algorithm for my homework.

Faced the "Memory Limit exceedeed" error.

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

> **Memory limit:**   8 Mb
>
> **Statement** You are to write a program that receives a weighted directed graph and finds all distances from fixed vertex S to all
> other vertices. Distance from S to some vertex W is the minimal length
> of path going from S to W. Length of path is the sum of weights of its
> arcs.
>
> **Input** file contains two integers N, M and S. Vertices are numbered
> with integer numbers from 1 to N. S is the number of source vertex. M
> is the number of arcs. Each of next M lines contain three integers —
> numbers of starting and ending vertices of some arc and its weight
> respectively. All weights are positive. There is at most one arc
> connecting two vertices in every direction.
>
> **Output** file must contain N numbers. Each I-th number is the distance
> from vertex S to vertex I. If some vertices are not reachable from S,
> corresponding numbers must be −1.
>
> **Constraints** 1 ≤ N, M ≤ 100000 All weights are less or equal 1000.

Sample test:

> 5 3 1 
> 1 2 5 
> 1 3 7 
> 3 4 10

Out: 0 5 7 17 -1

My programm:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define INF 100001

typedef enum {max, min} Heap_type;
typedef struct {
    Heap_type type;
    int *data, size;
} Heap;

Heap init_heap(Heap_type type, int size){
    Heap * heap = (Heap*)malloc(sizeof(Heap));

    if (heap!=NULL)
    {
        heap->data = (int *) malloc(size * sizeof(int));
        heap->type = type;
        heap->size = 0;
    }
    return *heap;
}

void swap(int *a, int *b){
    int tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}

void sift_up(Heap *heap, int id){
    heap->size++;
    while(heap->type == max ? (heap->data[id] > heap->data[(id - 1) / 2]) : (heap->data[id] < heap->data[(id - 1) / 2])){
        swap(&(heap->data[id]), &(heap->data[(id - 1) / 2]));
        id = (id - 1) / 2;
    }
}

void sift_down(Heap *heap, int id){
    int child_l, child_r, child_tmp;
    while(2 * id + 1 < heap->size){
        child_l = 2 * id + 1;
        child_r = 2 * id + 2;
        child_tmp = child_l;

        if(child_r < heap->size)
            if(heap->type == max ? heap->data[child_r] > heap->data[child_l] : heap->data[child_r] < heap->data[child_l])
                child_tmp = child_r;

        if(heap->type == max ? heap->data[id] >= heap->data[child_tmp] : heap->data[id] <= heap->data[child_tmp])
            break;

        swap(&(heap->data[id]), &(heap->data[child_tmp]));
        id = child_tmp;
    }
}

void push(Heap *heap, int num){
    heap->data[heap->size] = num;
    sift_up(heap, heap->size);
}

int get_root(Heap *heap){
    int root = heap->data[0];
    heap->size--;
    heap->data[0] = heap->data[heap->size];
    sift_down(heap, 0);
    return root;
}

void fast_dijkstra(int s, int *d, int n, int m, int **W, Heap pq){
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
        d[i] = INF;

    d[s] = 0;
    push(&pq, s);

    while (pq.size){
        int v = get_root(&pq);

        for(int u = 0; u<n; ++u) {
            if (W[v][u] && (d[v] + W[v][u]) < d[u]) {
                d[u] = d[v] + W[v][u];
                push(&pq, u);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    FILE *inp = fopen("input.txt", "r"),
            *out = fopen("output.txt", "w");

    int N, M, S;
    fscanf(inp, "%d %d %d", &N, &M, &S);
    S -= 1;

    int **W = (int **)malloc(N*sizeof(int *));
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        W[i] = (int *)calloc(N, sizeof(int));
    }

    for (int _=M; _; _--){
        int from, to, path;
        fscanf(inp,"%d %d %d", &from, &to, &path);
        W[from - 1][to - 1] = path;
    }

    Heap pq = init_heap(min,N);
    int d[N];

    fast_dijkstra(S, d, N, M, W, pq);

    for (int i = 0; i<N; ++i)
        fprintf(out, "%d ", d[i] != INF ? d[i] : -1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look as if you were ever checking for errors, so I wonder where you got that error message from. Please provide a [mcve], including the output it generates.

Comment: The error message probably comes from some kind of judging system. Can you specify the memory constraints in your question?

Comment: You use a dense graph representation which consumes O(N*M) memory. You must use a sparse representation which size is proportional to the number of edges.